# How can I fix the ViewPager issue?

Tags: java, android

I am using the android studio.
And using ViewPager with several fragments.
But the fragment's "OnCreateView", "OnResume" is called, though it was not selected in ViewPager.
I am not sure how can I detect these event.
Thank you.

Comment: ViewPager starts following fragments automatically, so that is normal

Comment: Yeah, it's normal, but need to load fragment when it is selected.

Comment: myViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);

Comment: Thanks  @adnbsr, but it's not working in my side.
Is there any other way to fix this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply solve this by this code:

Java code:

```java
// viewpager
viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter=new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);

// tab layout setup
tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
tabLayout.setTabTextColors(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.WHITE));
tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_FIXED);
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

Where:

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        super(fragmentManager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        if(position == 0) return new Request();
        if(position == 1) return new Open();
        if(position == 2) return new Closed();

        throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected position " + position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        if(position == 0) return "One";
        if(position == 1) return "Two";
        if(position == 2) return "Three";
      
        throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected position " + position);
    }
}
```

XML code:

```xml
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
android:id="@+id/tabs"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
style="@style/MyCustomTabLayout"
app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
app:tabMode="fixed"
app:tabGravity="fill"
/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
But still not fixed ViewPager issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "detect these events".

Still, the ViewPager will create the current fragment that is on the screen, *as well as* the fragment's before and after the current one-- this is so if the user swipes they show up immediately.

For example:  If the Viewpager's current position is 2, then fragment 1 and fragment 3 will be created.

You can customize this behavior by calling:

`myViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(NUM_ITEMS-1);`

Comment: Thanks @edthethird
I am using this method in my project, but it's not working.

`viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(0);
`
I want to load fragment after it is selected.

Comment: 1 is the minimum I believe.  In the logs you might see something like: `Requested offscreen page limit 0 too small; defaulting to 1
`

Comment: `setOffscreenPageLimit(1);`
it's not working in my side.